# Android: How to customize selectors for items in ActionBar?

Tags: android

I would like to programmatically set the background of an ActionBar item to draw as a specific color.

For a View I would accomplish this by setting the background of the View to a custom selector, which uses my specific color for the "selected" state; then I would call View.setSelected(boolean) to toggle the specific color on and off.

Is there a way to accomplish the same effect for items in the ActionBar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the styling of the action bar is done via images so I think the only way to do this is by creating a custom style or theme. See here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html for more detail and also check out the sample code here http://code.google.com/p/styled-action-bar/ .

Comment: Thanks, so I should be able to set a selector with this: "android:selectableItemBackground", and I can use my own selector that has some special color for the "selected" state.  But how do I get access to the ActionBar item to call View.setSelected()?

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not want to do this in XML? You can get the ActionBar object by using
            ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

Comment: Well, I would like it to be able to change the background color dynamically.  ActionBar doesn't seem to expose a way to find the individual Views for the corresponding MenuItems?

Comment: Ok, I was able to get the individual View with Activity.findViewById(id), where id comes from MenuItem.getItemId() for the corresponding MenuItem.

Comment: @ab11 Glad you got it sorted. Hopefully in the future the documentation for the actionbar will be increased.